# How to open file for each Python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have six threads

```
class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        super(ConsumerThread, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue


    def run(self):
        item = queue.get()
        parser = MyHTMLParser()
        new_con = parser.feed(item)
        print(new_con)
        queue.task_done()
```

I want to put new_con into file, with single file for one thread.

Comment: Do you care about the naming for each file?

Comment: Use the `open` function? What exactly is the problem? Are you having trouble coming up with unique file names?

Comment: @Rawing Now,where should I place the open and how to be thread independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        super(ConsumerThread, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue


    def run(self):
        item = queue.get()
        parser = MyHTMLParser()
        new_con = parser.feed(item)
        with open('file_name-%s' % self.getName(),
                  mode='w', encoding='utf8') as f:
            print(new_con, file=f)
        queue.task_done()
```

This will produce files with names like `file_name-Thread-1` etc.  You might want to use something nicer than this, but as a first shot, this solves your issues.